# Is it appropriate to research a question poster's background and reference it in a comment/answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I asked a question on Workplace. Others took the liberty of exploring my background and resume even though I didn't ask for it. My resume and background are linked to from my profile so they are obviously in the public domain, but I feel that referencing them wasn't necessary to answer the question. I don't think looking at my background amounted to anything more than ad hominem criticism.

Is there a policy on doing this kind of "detective work" into a users background and referencing it in a comment or answer? Is it encouraged, allowed, discouraged, or banned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general principle on Stack Exchange is to address **the post not the person**—whether that is voting or answering or what have you. Comments *can* be more personal since you're often directly conversing or addressing a specific person, but the same general rule should apply. If the comment is not relevant to the post then flag it as not constructive or too chatty.

If your resume and background are linked to in your profile then there is no problem with people reading that information (if you think there is, simply remove it). If that information is directly relevant to the post and someone uses that information then there is nothing really wrong with that. If the information was taken in to account where it wasn't really relevant then explain that to the answerer in a comment. If they ignore your comment, at worst that makes it a bad answer (to which you downvote, nothing more).

However—regardless of where the information came from—if a comment or answer in any way goes again the [Be Nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy then flag it as rude or abusive.

Comment: Worth pointing out that an authors background, is relevant, if they are asking about job interviews and what they should do about reasonable or (in their eyes) unreasonable requests that come out from that interview

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't see the specific question so I don't know, maybe it was relevant, maybe not. I can see that information like that is more likely to be relevant in that case, but the asker could be asking a hypothetical question not actually relevant to their personal situation.

Comment: @Cal Hypothetical questions at workplace are not on topic

Comment: @Ramhound source? I don't think that's true (help certainly doesn't say so and the only meta post I can see is with regards to a hypothetical *tag*), it's certainly not enforceable so if it's true it makes little sense.

Comment: @Cal Well the question the author asked at Workplace wasn't hypothectical so it does not matter.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not prohibited to do your research and look into readily available public information when looking to answer a question.  They most certainly haven't done anything that would be prohibited.  As to whether or not it's encouraged, you'd need to ask that on that site's meta, as that's the type of convention that would be site specific.  I'm not a member of that community, but it certainly seems acceptable given what I saw on that question, and I don't see any problem with it.  It helps them provide better answers, as was the case here, and it's a practice that I expect would regularly aid in improving answers (unlike, say, SO, where such information simply wouldn't be useful).

The answers you got were *much* more helpful to you given that the answerers knew a bit more about you and your situation than you had provided.  Had they not done so, their answers would likely have provided lots of information not applicable to you that would have been, at best, not helpful to you, or worse, actively harmful if you hadn't realized that they didn't apply to you.

Nothing about those answers were ad hominem.  They weren't using arguments to attempt to disguise or distract from the issues at hand, they were using *relevant* information about your history to answer a question about what you should do in a given situation (which is *highly* dependant on specific information about you).  If they were actually looking up this information purely to personally insult you, rather than to provide a higher quality answer to your quesiton, then such insults would of course be against the rules (the research itself wouldn't be the problem, but rather such inappropriate usage of it), but that's not what happened.